# Angular datatable grouping

Tags: angular, datatables

I have a datatable of 7 columns(header) which is fixed. Inside tbody i wanted to display the data in the below format
[image].

I have tried using two rows in tbody, displaying first two data in the td in first row and rest other data in another row which displays fine. But when I use dtTrigger, table doesn't display like expected(all the grouped one's will be displayed at the bottom and non-grouped in the beginning). I am using this.dtTrigger.next(this.dtOptions) inside the subscribe after assigning the response to a variable but it does not display properly. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code

```
this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        searching: true,
        info: false,
        columnDefs:[
          { targets:0, orderable: true },
          { targets:1, orderable: false },
          { targets:2, orderable: false },
          { targets:3, orderable: false },
          { targets:4, orderable: false },
          { targets:5, orderable: false },
          { targets:6, orderable: false },
        ],
        "lengthMenu": [[25,50,75, -1], [25,50,75,"All"]],
            language: {
                search:'',
                searchPlaceholder: 'Search ',
                paginate: {
                    first: '',
                    previous:
                      '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="7.63" height="14" viewBox="0 0 7.63 14"> <path id="Aero-left-icon" d="M7,7.63l-7-7L.63,0,7,6.37,13.37,0,14,.63Z" transform="translate(7.63) rotate(90)"/> </svg>',
                    next: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="7.631" height="14" viewBox="0 0 7.631 14"><path id="Aero-right-icon" d="M7,0,0,7l.63.63L7,1.261l6.37,6.37L14,7Z" transform="translate(7.631) rotate(90)"/></svg>',
                    last: '',
                  }
              },
        drawCallback: function (settings) {
          let api = settings.oInstance.api();
          let rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
          let last: any = null;

          api.column(0, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group: any, i: any) {
                    if (last !== group) {                      
                        $(rows)
                        .eq(i)
                        .before(
                          '<tr class="group"><td colspan="6" class="project-vehicle-row">' +
                            group +
                            '</td></tr>'
                        );                     
                      last = group;
                    }
                  });
        }
 api.column(1, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group: any, i: any) {
                    if (last !== group) {                      
                        $(rows)
                        .eq(i)
                        .before(
                          '<tr class="group"><td colspan="6" class="project-vehicle-row">' +
                            group +
                            '</td></tr>'
                        );                     
                      last = group;
                    }
                  });
        }
    }

public someMethod(){
this.rerender();
this.someService.getDetails().subscribe(res => {
this.someVar = res.response;
this.dtTrigger.next(this.dtOptions);
// other code
})
}
```

```
<table class=" table table-bordered  table-condensed table-responsive tableResize" datatable
   [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" style="word-wrap: break-word; margin-bottom: 0px;display: table !important;">
<thead style="background-color: #48a0c1;">
      <tr>
          <th style="width: 20%;text-align: left;">
              <span>Name</span>
          </th>
          ......... similarly other 6 columns
      </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody style=" height: auto;" >
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of CalculationList; let i = index">
<tr class="grouping" >
          <td class="project-vehicle-row" style="width: 20%">
              <a > {{group.Name}} </a> </td>
          <td class="project-vehicle-row" style="width: 20%">
              <a > {{group.vehicle}} </a> </td>
          <td class="project-vehicle-row" style="width: 10%"> </td>
          <td class="project-vehicle-row" style="width: 20%"> </td>
          <td class="project-vehicle-row" style="width: 10%"> </td>
          <td class="project-vehicle-row" style="width: 15%"> </td>          
          <td class="project-vehicle-row" style="width: 10%"> </td>
      </tr>
<tr>
              <td style="width: 20%;text-align: left; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                  <a></a>
              </td>
              <td style="width: 20%;text-align: left; padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                  <a></a>
              </td>
              <td style="width: 10%;text-align: left; padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                  <a > {{ group.Number }} </a>
              </td>
              <td style="width: 20%;text-align: left; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                  {{ group.task }}
              </td>
              <td style="width: 10%;text-align: left; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                  <a > {{ group.call }}</a>
              </td>
              <td style="width: 15%;text-align: left; padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                  {{ group.pro }}
              </td>              
              <td style="width: 10%;text-align: left; padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                  {{ group.nStatus }}
              </td>
          </tr>
</ng-container>
</tbody>
</table>
```